# jQuery Autocomplete Not Working on Hosted Site

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the following code for autocompleting search textbox in my website. The code is working fine on localhost but when the site is hosted the "error" box pops up.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SearchText();
});
function SearchText() {
    $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Index.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'location':'" + document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearch').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and the function code is:

```
[WebMethod]

public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string location)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string connect = @"
         Data Source=jaipurrooms.db.11458954.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=jaipurrooms;
         User ID=xyz;
         Password=xyz;";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Location from Details where Location LIKE '%'+@location+'%'", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dr["Location"].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use full URL instead? You can catch your ajax call both request and response with fiddler2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your url in ajax request. Try to use the following syntax :

```
url: "./Index.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
```